# Problem with getting data from external source by Rest Template

Tags: java, resttemplate

I have some problem with getting response from external resources with RestTemplate.

What I want to get is data from PokemonApi: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/

I thought about creating 2 Classes that will contain that data(Not using Object and headers)

My 2 classes are like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MainResponse {
    @JsonProperty("typeList")
    private List<PokemonType> pokemonTypes;
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PokemonType {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String pokemonType;
}
```

What problem I got is that I can't extract any data from my RestTemplate class:

```
public MainResponse response() {
    Optional<MainResponse> search = Optional.ofNullable(
            restTemplate.getForObject("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type", MainResponse.class)
    );
    return search.orElseGet(MainResponse::new);
}
```

I'm not sure why its not working right. I can't get any response and everything is ending in errors when I try get response. Please someone look at that and give me some pointers.

It will be surely eyeopener for all RestTemplates in the future for me :) Thanks alot.

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Have you searched for examples on using RestTemplate? or perhaps for the error you are getting.  Does the Pokemon api require any special treatment, such as certain headers being supplied, does it return Json at all? I.e have you checked that you are accessing the API in the correct manner?

Comment: I think Pokemon Api is one of the simple ones that don't require tokens etc. I have tried to check of usage of RestTemplate and I was doing the same as in internet. But still not working. As for error i have made a screen: https://postimg.cc/9wCJJw3Y